# Bathroom LED light flickers on WW mode only

Tags: led

I moved to my new apartment a month ago, and the LED light in the bathroom was working fine, but it starts to flicker from a week a ago, and is getting worse day by day (give me the impression that it's going to stop working soon).

Today I opened the cover of the bathroom light and change the switch from WW (Warm White) to CW (Cool White) mode, the flicker then stopped. I was wondering why this is happening. And if there's anything I can do to fix the LED on WW mode.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several LEDs in line and one of them has a broken bond-wire, this creates the flickering. The connection is mostly depended from the temperature.

To repair this, you have to remove the lamp from the powerline, put it on your bench and find the one faulty LED with a multi-meter.

The problem is the temperature-dependant problem.

The white LEDs have not been used as much, so they are like new and they do not have a broken bond-wires.

The new LEDs have a flip chip technology, which means they are soldered directly onto the aluminium-PCB and they do not have any bond-wire.

Comment: +1 on bond-wire.

Comment: I am German and not extremely good in English, so I hope that I do not have to much misspelling here. JRE is correcting it mostly and I try to learn.

Comment: There aren't too many mistakes here, and nothing that makes the answer hard to understand. I've suggested some corrections.

Comment: Thank you very much Lord Teddy.

Comment: Very nice answer. There's also a *slight* chance that it's just the switch, in which case exercising it back and forth might fix things. I wouldn't count on that though.

Comment: @KMJ - This is a possibility too, the contact can get oxidized or simply dirty, but this steady flickering is in the most cases because of such a bonding problem. I have seen this a lot and could fix it.